# Live debugging a nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, debugging

How can I debug a running nodejs app? I've found tools such as `node-inspector`, but it seems to only support starting the app and debugging from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Debugging a running nodejs app.**

This is the combination of a little documented feature of V8 mixed with a non-documented feature of the node.js debugger client. Say you have an already running node process that you want to debug.

```
# start the remote debugger in the already running node process
kill -s USR1 pid
# attach to the debugger using the node.js client
node debug host:5858
# see where you are
debug> pause
debug> bt
```

From there you can poke around. You can also continue and pause again to see if you seem to consistently end up in the same code area.

**Debugging a nodejs app.**

V8 comes with an extensive debugger which is accessible out-of-process via a simple TCP protocol. Node has a built-in client for this debugger. To use this, start Node with the debug argument; a prompt will appear:

```
% node debug myscript.js
< debugger listening on port 3000
connecting... ok
break in /home/username/Code/myscript.js:1
  1 x = 5;
  2 setTimeout(function () {
  3   debugger;
debug>
```

- cont, c - Continue execution
- next, n - Step next
- step, s - Step in
- out, o - Step out
- pause - Pause running code

Check [API](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) for other commands reference and other details

You can also use [node-inspector](http://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) . Use it from any browser supporting websockets. Breakpoints, profiler, livecoding etc... It is really awesome.

Install it with

```
npm install -g node-inspector
```

then run

```
node-debug app.js
```